# UIBarButtonItem frame changes

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am putting a UIView directly under particular bar buttons. I have a function to find the frame of the bar button here

```
    func frameForBarButton(btn: UIBarButtonItem) -> CGRect {
        let view: UIView = btn.valueForKey("view") as! UIView
        return view.frame
    }
```

which I call in the initial view controllers ViewdidlayoutSubviews: and it prints

```
bar button 1 frame: (270.0, 5.0, 54.0, 32.0)
```

I call it again in dispatch_after(2 seconds) and it prints

```
bar button 1 frame: (254.0, 5.0, 54.0, 32.0)
```

I am confused as to A. What could be moving this?? B. Is there a way to know when the UIBarButtonItemFrames have been layed out?

Comment: Couldn't you just set an auto layout constraint so the UIView follows the group of buttons?